# Command to hide everything except viewport in terminal window?

Tags: terminal, workspaces, window-management

Is there a way to see only the viewport for terminal (Mac OS X 10.8.4)? (That is, can I hide the open/close/minimize buttons.)

The need is for more for a visual desire than a practical one. I'm working on a  command-line tool and I want to hide everything else for the user.

Comment: Which terminal? Any? What window manager and desktop environment? (http://xwinman.org/)

Comment: The user can do this themselves. I don't see why you should force it on them for purely aesthetic reasons.

Comment: @Sukminder Mac OS X 10.8.4, the basic terminal.

Comment: @Wutaz I mostly agree with you. I still want to know how to do it. :D

Comment: @cathy.sasaki: Sorry. Have no OS X to play with here, – so not much help I can offer. Had a quick search and it does not look to promising unless you write your own version of *Terminal*. Use the term *"title bar"* when you search. E.g. `os x hide title bar`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be Configured via Compiz

http://www.maketecheasier.com/terminal-as-transparent-wallpaper-in-ubuntu/2008/05/21

Requires CompizFusion that is come preinstalled if you are running Ubuntu Gutsy or Hardy. If your computer does not supports Compiz, you can follow the method [here](http://www.maketecheasier.com/terminal-as-transparent-wallpaper-in-ubuntu/2008/05/21#devilspie)

Comment: I'm on OS X not Ubuntu and don't have apt-get. Anything I can do?